# Transfer input value to div used as submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to transfer the value of an input to a div that I use as a submit button?

Example:

```
<form action="./exam/x/u_exam_run.exe.php" method="post" style="display:inline">
  <input type="hidden" name="qst" value="<?=$get_QUID_text_sha;?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="uex" value="<?=$_get_EUID;?>" />
  <?php
    foreach($question_answers as $answer_text_sha => $answer_text) {
       if($reformat_output) {
         $answer_text = reformat_output_table($answer_text);
       }
  ?>      
  <div name="akwMB" class="<?=$_SESSION['akw_list'][$get_QUID_text_sha]==$answer_text_sha ? 'list-item-answer-hover' : 'list-item-answer';?>" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">
    <input type="hidden" name="akwMB" value="<?=$answer_text_sha;?>"/>
    <div class="question-list" >
      <span><?=$answer_text;?></span>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</form>
```

I'm trying to get `$answer_text_sha` to get submitted when I click the div, but everything I've tried didn't work. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: First why do you wanna do this? Second you can't submit a form by clicking a div, for do that you have to use javascript or jquery doom event. .

Comment: The form submits, but only the last value of the input. There are 4 answers to a question, no matter which one I click, it submits the last. onclick="this.parentNode.submit()" does the submit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work, I don't know how OK my solution is but I used increment for each answer id and used `<label for="id">`.

If anyone needs this by any chance, this is how I did it

```
<input id="MB<?=$i++;?>" style="display:none;" type="submit" name="akwMB" value="<?=$answer_text_sha;?>"/>
  <label for="MB<?=$ii++;?>">
    <div name="akwMB" class="<?=$_SESSION['akw_list'][$get_QUID_text_sha]==$answer_text_sha ? 'list-item-answer-hover' : 'list-item-answer';?>" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">                             
       <div class="question-list" >
         <span><?=$answer_text;?></span>    
       </div>
     </div>
  </label>
```